# Facebook authentication for Cognito user pool without hosted UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, facebook-login, amazon-cognito

I am building a web app and I would like to accomplish the following:

1. Authenticate/store users using AWS Cognito User Pools (Not "Identity Pools")
2. Allow users to sign in with both Facebook and username/password.
3. Use my own UI (not the hosted UI offered by AWS)

I have set up a User Pool with Facebook as an Identity Provider and an app client, but I can't seem to figure out how I can actually let users sign up.

I've tried a number of things using `aws-amplify` and `amazon-cognito-identity-js`, but everything ends up only authenticating the user in the "identity pool" (which I don't really understand why I even need one just to use "user pools").

Considering the AWS mobile SDKs somehow accomplish authentication without requiring the redirects used by the hosted UI, I would think it must be possible to also do this on the web.